# connecting mysql database in vb

Tags: mysql, vb.net

im encountering a problem with the connections of my MySql database. I try to install the mysql connector version 6.9.9 but it only shows the same data source i have before.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8q79.png)

Comment: The connector allows your app to access a MySQL database in code.  It doesnt look like you have the server running or installed (I think the designer will start the service if it is not already running).

Answer (score -1):

Well...this seems like a stopped service.
run>msconfig>services>check it